# When is a computed property not reactive?

Tags: vue.js

I have a Vue page which gathers information from external JSON sources, and then uses it to compute a property.

Problem: this property is not reactive (= it is not recomputed when underlying data changes)

```
<div id="app">
    <div v-for="tag in filteredTags">{{tag}}</div>
</div>

<script>
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        tags: {},
        allTags: {},
    },
    computed: {
        // provides an Array of tags which are selected
        filteredTags() {
            let t = Object.keys(this.allTags).filter(x => this.allTags[x])
            console.log(t)
            return t
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        // get source tags
        fetch("tags.json")
        .then(r => r.json())
        .then(r => {
            this.tags = r
            console.log(JSON.stringify(this.tags))
            // bootstrap a tags reference where all the tags are selected
            Object.keys(this.tags).forEach(t => {
                this.allTags[t] = true
            });
            console.log(JSON.stringify(this.allTags))
        })
    }
})
</script>
```

The file which is fetched (`{"tag1":["/posts/premier/"],"post":["/posts/premier/","/posts/second/"]}`) is correctly processed in `mounted()`, the output on the console is

```
{"tag1":["/posts/premier/"],"post":["/posts/premier/","/posts/second/"]}
{"tag1":true,"post":true}
```

**`filteredTags` is however empty**. On the console, I see it displayed (as `[]`) right at the start of the processing of the page, which is initially fine (first compute, when `allTags` is empty), but is then not computed anymore when `allTags` changes (after `tags.json` is fetched, processed and `allTags` correctly updated).

**Why isn't this reactive?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vue isn't reactive to properties that didn't exist when the object was added to `data`

Since your `tag` and `allTags` are empty objects with no properties (yet), any properties added after aren't reactive automatically.

To solve this you have to use the `Vue.Set` or `this.$set` functions provided by Vue.
the `Set` function accepts the values `this.$set(object, key, value)`

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    tags: {},
    allTags: {},
  },
  computed: {
    // provides an Array of tags which are selected
    filteredTags() {
      let t = Object.keys(this.allTags).filter(x => this.allTags[x])
      return t
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    const r = '{"tag1":["/posts/premier/"],"post":["/posts/premier/","/posts/second/"]}';
    const rJson = JSON.parse(r);
    // You shouldn't need to use $set here as you replace the entire object, instead of adding properties
    this.tags = rJson;
    
    Object.keys(this.tags).forEach(t => {
      // Change this
      //this.allTags[t] = true;
      
      // To this
      this.$set(this.allTags, t, true);
    });
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="tag in filteredTags">{{tag}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I just read again [reactivity in depth](https://it.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html) and was about to update my question with the same findings as yours. And your update about `this.tags = rJson` just answered my remaining question :)